# Вызов метода JS класса

Tags: c++, node.js

```
static void glfw_WindowPosFun(GLFWwindow* window, int x, int y) {
    Window* w = (Window*)glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window);
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    Local<Value> value = w->handle()->Get(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "onPosition"));
    if (value->IsFunction()) {
        Local<Function> fn = Local<Function>::Cast(value);
        Local<Value> argv[] = {
            Int32::New(isolate, x),
            Int32::New(isolate, y)
        };
        fn->Call(Null(isolate), 2, argv);
    }
}
```

Есть класс Window связанный с JS классом (класс обертка). Нужно вызвать JS метод входящий в состав класса `Window`. Приведенный пример работает, но `this` при вызове указывает не на класс владелец метода, а на непонятно что.

Есть ли возможность сделать вызов от имени класса?

**Обновление**

`this` - это `this` в `JavaScript` коде, класс которому принадлежит метод
V8 — движок JavaScript с открытым программным кодом, `Node.js` — программная платформа, основанная на движке V8.

Обертка - способ вызывать с++ функции методы и т.п. из JavaScript кода запущенного под V8 (node.js)

Для ответа надо знание архитектуры V8. На данный момент проблема решена передачей в вызов функции  хендлера класса Window, правильно это или нет не знаю, так как в доках  нет упоминания (не нашол) Object имеет отношение к `Context`, но сработало, кто знает правильно и что я сделал такой подстановкой, буду признателен.

Пример работы

```
glfw.setWindowCloseCallback(window, function(){
        this.width = 100; /* <<-- тот самый this */
});
```

Comment: Мне кажется не хватает каких-то делатей. Так упомянается glfw, которая не входит в NodeJS, и упомянается связь через обертки, реализация которых не ясна.